# How can I create the cell structure of Matlab in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to create my own data type in C# which is like Matlab's cell structure. See the following example.

a{1,1}=[1 2 3;
4 5 6];

a{1,2}=[3 2 3;
3 1 6];

a{2,1}=[0 2 5;
4 1 6];

a{2,2}=[0 2 1;
4 4 4];

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution (using different matrices):

```
using System;

namespace jagged_array_learning
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int[,] m1 = new int[2,2];
        int[,] m2 = new int[2,2];
        int[,] m3 = new int[2,2];
        int[,] m4 = new int[2,2];

        m1[0,0] = 1;
        m1[0,1] = 2;
        m1[1,0] = 3;
        m1[1,1] = 4;

        m2[0,0] = 5;
        m2[0,1] = 6;
        m2[1,0] = 7;
        m2[1,1] = 8;

        m3[0,0] = 9;
        m3[0,1] = 10;
        m3[1,0] = 11;
        m3[1,1] = 12;

        m4[0,0] = 13;
        m4[0,1] = 14;
        m4[1,0] = 15;
        m4[1,1] = 16;

        int[,][,] a = new int[2,2][,];

        a[0,0] = m1;
        a[0,1] = m2;
        a[1,0] = m3;
        a[1,1] = m4;


        Console.WriteLine(a[0,1][1,0]);




    }
}
```

}